# Is json_encode extremely picky?

Tags: javascript, php, session, json

It appears that json_encode is being VERY picky about what other stuff can be inside my PHP file. Which is fine, because I just do what I normally would do in file A (with json_encode) in it's own file.

I just thought I would ask because I am storing a variable in the $_SESSION instead of updating my database with the variable because json_encode doesn't seem to want to work when I have all of the code in its file.

For instance, this code doesn't work:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'dbcon.php';

    $sessionID = uniqid();
    echo json_encode($sessionID);

    if(isSet($_POST['clearSession']) == '1')
    {
        $query = "UPDATE currentID SET id=('0')";
        $execute = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    } else {
        $query = "UPDATE currentID SET id=('$sessionID')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    }

?>
```

When going to the file in my browser, I do in fact get the json_encode results, however when my Javascript calls it it doesn't seem to correctly import it.

So, for now I simply have two PHP files:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $sessionID = uniqid();
    $_SESSION["sessionID"] = $sessionID;
    echo json_encode($sessionID);
?>
```

Which echo's the same thing as in the first file, but this time my JavaScript correctly imports it.

and

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'dbcon.php';
    if(isSet($_POST['clearSession']) == '1')
    {
        $query = "UPDATE currentID SET id=('0')";
        $execute = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    } else {
        $sessionID = $_SESSION["sessionID"];
        $query = "UPDATE currentID SET id=('$sessionID')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    }
?>
```

I guess my question is, why does this happen? It seems kind of silly that I have to store the uniqid in a SESSION so that my other PHP file can add it to the database. Whereas if I simply had it in one file, then I could just update the database when I generate a new uniqid and avoid having to use $_SESSION in the first place.

Comment: indenting code. A really good idea if you want real people to help you. Be nice to us please.

Comment: I used ctrl+K so it looks fine on my end.

Comment: your end is not the end of every person you're asking for help. That said, what is the actual output of json_encode when you echo/print it? I find it hard to believe it's actually the problem here. (you have the echo in your code, what does it log to terminal/cmd?)

Comment: I don't think I understand your english when you say "my end is not the end of every person", sorry :( The output of both files is "53d4be32bde4e" or a variant of that. However, one successfully imports while the other does not.

Comment: The problem is that you see JSON as a black box. It isn't. It's just text, and a fairly simple format. You need to see the exact output generated by PHP, not just feed it to JavaScript and see happens at the end. Options range from opening the *.php URL in your browser (they're many ways to fake POST data) or just using your browser console ("Net" pane in most browsers).

Comment: I understand that it is simply text (Just like encoding a string to md5) - what I do not understand is why one way works and the other does not.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. I was trying to say that you need to **see** with your own eyes what that text looks like. For that purpose, I suggested a couple of alternatives. If you need additional hints to put them into practice feel free to ask.

Comment: Ahh, as I said in the other comment, both files output something similar to this "53d4be32bde4e"

Comment: Then none should work. That is not valid JSON (valid JSON starts with `[` or `{`). You can validate it with e.g. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Oh, I think I got it... Let me compose an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I am almost 100% sure that using double quotes is valid JSON. Unless I am encoding an array it's double-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
$sessionID = uniqid();
echo json_encode($sessionID); // "53d4c17abfe87"
```

Since `uniqid()` produces a plain string, your output is not valid JSON as per the [format specification](http://json.org/). You'll need something like this instead:

```
$sessionID = uniqid();
echo json_encode(array($sessionID)); // ["53d4c17abfe87"]
```

Why does `json_encode()` generate invalid JSON in the first place? Because some times it's useful to generate partial JSON. For instance, it's a handy trick to inject values into generated JavaScript code:

```
var foo = <?=json_encode($sessionID)?>;
```

It's also [documented](http://php.net/json_encode):

> PHP implements a superset of JSON - it will also encode and decode
>   scalar types and NULL. The JSON standard only supports these values
>   when they are nested inside an array or an object.

So to answer the question title:

> Is json_encode extremely picky?

On the contrary, it's fairly relaxed!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, I still don't understand why one way works and the other doesn't when they both output the same thing :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store it in a session necessarily, it's the fact that $_SESSION is an array.

So, what you would want would be something like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('sessionID' => $sessionID));
```

And then when you parse the JSON with JavaScript you can access it like this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
alert(obj.sessionID);
```

Obviously, `jsonObj` is the JSON passed from the server.

Hope this helps!